# Getting Absolute Differences Between Consecutive Data Values in R

Tags: r

I currently have a column data (all integers) of 296 random numbers. I'd like to get the absolute difference between consecutive values as a new column.

(so, the new column would consist of |val. 2 - val. 1|, |val. 3 - val. 2|, |val 4. - val. 3|... etc.)

I would use a for loop with append and a new list in Python, but it doesn't seem like I can do that in R. What ways could I do this in R? Thank you.

Comment: try `diff(x, lag = 1)` or `newcolumn = c(NA, diff(x, lag = 1))`

Comment: @missuse He/she also need `abs` for the absolute values.

Comment: @Stéphane Laurent Thanks, I missed that part `c(NA, abs(diff(z, lag = 1)))`

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `diff` and `abs`.

```
dd <- data.frame(x = rpois(20, 10))
dd$diff = c(NA, abs(diff(dd$x)))

> dd
    x diff
1  12   NA
2  16    4
3   8    8
4  16    8
5   2   14
6  18   16
7   4   14
8   8    4
9  10    2
10 13    3
11  9    4
12 10    1
13  9    1
14 14    5
15 10    4
16 10    0
17 16    6
18 12    4
19 10    2
20 17    7
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!